# How to replicate the Mac OS X fade out "screensaver" with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, macos, screensaver

You know how on Macs after about 2-3 minutes of no activity it fades out the screen partially — the same on iOS? Well, I want to replicate this on a web page with jQuery.

I know how to make it fade and all, but I don't know how to make it actually work after 2 or 3 minutes of no mouse move or key presses.

I've researched this on Google and I just keep getting "How to display a webpage as a screensaver on Mac OS X" which is not what I want.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: iOS fades the screen brightness.  You can't do that in jQuery.

Comment: post your existing code - maybe on jsfiddle.com if appropriate

Comment: @SLaks Well, I would just have to have a div fade in over the page. But my question was how to make this happen after no activity.

Comment: What for? It would just be annoying.

Comment: @Slaks That's true, never really thought about that. I'm still gonna try it though to see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (untested)

```
// set the last event time to now on page loading
var lastEvent = new Date();

function fadeOut(){
    // your fade out routine
}

// bind appropriate events to everything
$('*').bind('keydown mousemove mousedown',function(){
    // set the lastEvent time to now after any event
    lastEvent = new Date();
})

// run this every second
setInterval(function(){
    // get current time
    var now = new Date();
    // compare to last event (minus 2 mins) and fade out if it was long enough
    if(lastEvent < now - (2 * 60 * 1000))
        fadeOut()
},1000)
```

Comment: This seems to take up a lot of CPU and it freezes the site sometimes and it usually always makes it laggy. Would your other code do that? I changed it to do that every 100 seconds but it still messes up after a while.

Comment: I would be surprised if either of them made the page lag - or consumed CPU as they do not have while loop, and don't execute a lot of code. The only thing I can imagine consuming - is binding to everything - if you have a lot of elements. Are you sure it is this code that is making it laggy?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like it because I put it in `/* */` and it isn't laggy anymore. If you would like to see the site (maybe you could see a problem with it) let me know and I can give you the URL to it.

Answer (score 3):

Handle the `keydown` and `mousemove` events, clear the timeout, then set a timeout to fade out in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this untested code:

```
function fadeOut(){
    // your fade out routine
}

// initialise the set timeout function to run fade out after 2 seconds
var x = setTimeout(function(){
    fadeOut()
},2000)

// bind appropriate events to everything
$('*').bind('keydown mousemove mousedown',function(){
    // clear the existing timeout and re-set it starting from now
    clearTimeout(x)
    x = setTimeout(function(){
        fadeOut()
    },2000)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your other code though and it works perfectly! I haven't tried this one though.

Comment: Happy days - just for the record, here is a working version of this method too: http://jsfiddle.net/JdmPB/